# Microsoft Azure - cannot transfer subscription

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have contacted Azure support, but that is very slow, and they don't see this as an important issue (it is to me...). They have also been unhelpful in the past.

I have a BizSpark Subscription that is several years old. On that subscription I have 24 resources. I need to transfer that entire subscription to someone else who also has an Azure Account. I go to my subscription and click the "Transfer" link, and I get the following error:

```
This subscription is not currently eligible to be transferred to another account. We're sorry about this and are actively working towards a resolution for you and anyone else inconvenienced by this issue. Please try again later, or contact support and request a resource migration instead.
```

If I go to a VM, and choose "Move Resource," I get this error:

```
Source subscription contains following application(s) which doesn't support migration: (5 websites mentioned),Source subscription contains following cloud service(s) which doesn't support migration: (1 service mentioned)
```

I have had other issues on this same subscription. Earlier this year, I tried to change the credit card attached to the subscription. It wouldn't let me. I never got this resolved.

Is there any way that I can transfer these items to another Azure account?

Comment: Have you referenced [Transfer ownership of an Azure subscription to another account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer#faq)?

Comment: I don't see anything there that will help. Thanks for the link, though.